# Can SWF read from external XML file in Google DFP?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

We created an SWF that reads from an XML file in another server, and everything works fine when it's two "normal" servers (the one with the SWF and the one with the XML file).

But the site we want to publish in uses Google DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP), and it seems that Google DFP doesn't allow the SWF to read from an external source. When they upload it,

Would that make sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Google DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) doesn't allow a swf to read from an external source.

Answer (score 0):

A SWF can load from an external server if you place a cross domain policy file at the root of the server hosting the subload.

Here's a basic cross domain file you can configure for your own use. Enter your domain or IP where it says "yourdomain.com". Then save the file as crossdomain.xml and upload it to the root of your server.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="yourdomain.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You can enter multiple URLS like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="yourdomain1.com"/>
<allow-access-from domain="yourdomain2.com"/>    
<allow-access-from domain="yourdomain3.com"/>    
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You can also use a wildcard "*" character to allow any domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>  
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You can also use this crossdomain.xml wizard: http://www.crossdomainmaker.com/

Comment: Thanks, we already have crossdomain.xml so that's why the SWF in one "regular" server is reading from the XML in another "regular" server. 
The problem is that the swf, uploaded through Google DFP, is not able to read from the XML file. I'm thinking that Google DFP doesn't allow that type of communication.